# Application availability management Best Practice

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, policy

In our architecture we have an identity and access manager ([CA SiteMinder®](http://www.ca.com/sg/secure-sso.aspx)) and a Java EE application under Jboss 5.
This application (an potentially many others) shoud have an availability policy associated (i.e. the application front-end should be accessible from 9:00am to 6:00pm, while the web services should be always available).
Would it be more correct to put this policy in the IAM or on the application side (i.e. implementing a servlet filter)?
Or none of the two is the correct place to put this kind of policy and I should consider another layer to put in the middle?

note: web services call don't go through the IAM.

Comment: I don't think there's a right answer. Personally, I would implement it myself in a filter, as it would allow me to test the configuration in an easier way... But you're already putting a lot of trust on SiteMinder, so you might want to add a bit more.

Comment: Thanks @Augusto. The problem with the filer-approach would be that the access policies will spread across all applications, and changing a policy (for an existing user, for instance) would result in changing multiple configurations across multiple applications.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful to understand your availability requirement more clearly, but anyway, here is my opinion.

As far as application architecture goes, I consider `security` and `availability` to be two distinct requirements.  I would therefore implement them separately.  From an architect's perspective, this is similar to the `Single-Responsibility` principle of object-oriented design where individual components of an object-oriented software system have only one responsibility at a time.

Keeping the two concerns separate will ensure that:

1. **Ease** - They can both be designed, implemented, tested and maintained easily.  I would be able to write automated tests for each separately, without having to worry about the wiring between the two.
2. **Extensibility** - Extending any one of the solutions individually will be easier because there will be less dependence on other parts of the system.  For instance, if the application grows into multiple modules or types of component, each with its own availability nuances, only one of the solutions will need to change.
3. **Lock-in** - Implementing your availability requirements within Site Minder may lock you in with that product.  You will have one more consideration in the future if you wish to migrate away from Site Minder.
4. **Impact on existing code** - You have mentioned that web service calls currently do not go through the IAM.  Implementing your availability solution using the IAM may have an impact on this aspect of the application.